# Create invite link for maximum 1 person to join only command/code

Tags: discord, discord.js

Yeah so I can't seem to find any code that creates a invite for max 1 person to join only. (I'm using module.exports)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this easily with the following code:

```
 message.channel.createInvite({
    maxUses: 1 //maximum times it can be used
  })
```

You can find more infos about this command on the docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createInvite